# <video> tag with downloaded path in ionic ios not loads the video

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, html5-video, ionic7

Download the video using `filetransfer` and then that video I try to open in  tag is not loading:

```
this.fileTransferDownload.download(this.videoUrl + this.videoObj.video_file_path, path + "Downloads/" + `${filename}`).then((entry: any) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.nativeURL);
      console.log('download complete: ', entry);
      let localurl: any = this.ionicView.convertFileSrc(entry.nativeURL);
      this.downloadURL = localurl;

<video id="singleVideo" style="width: 100%;"
```

```
  loop webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" poster="{{mediaUrl+videoObj.video_thumb}}" 
        playsinline="true" controls preload="none" >
        <source *ngIf="downloadURL" src="{{downloadURL}}" type="video/mp4">
          <source *ngIf="!downloadURL" src="{{videoUrl+videoObj.video_file_path}}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

**Problem:**
`downloadURl` loads in Android **but not in iOS**.

In iOS the result is that it's showing a blank screen of white.

I tried to convert a `file://` URL into a URL that is compatible with the local web server in the Web View plugin. 
This works in Android but not works in iOS.

I need any solution for iOS to playback a video using downloaded file bytes instead of a URL path.